# Why is a .NET unit test covering a Parallel.foreach loop hardware-dependent?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, parallel.foreach

I'm using Moq to unit test some code that includes a `Parallel.foreach` loop.

The *Arrange* phase sets up 4 exceptions to be thrown within the loop and then wrapped in an `AggregateException`.

This passed on my i7 processor and I checked in the code.

Afterwards, a colleague complained it wasn't passing for him. It turned out `Parallel.foreach` was only spawning 2 threads on his Core2duo before bombing out and hence only 2 exceptions were wrapped in the `AggregateException`.

The question is what to do about this so the unit test doesn't depend on processor architecture? A couple of thoughts:-

1. There is a [Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460695.aspx) on manually adding exceptions to
   the `AggregateException` but we're not keen on doing this as the loop
   should exit at the earliest opportunity if there is a problem.
2. [`ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) can
   put an upper limit on the number of threads used. But unless this is turned down
   to 1 (which seems more like cheating than proper unit testing) how
   can the unit test know how many threads will actually be used and
   hence set up the *Arrange* and *Assert* phases propertly?

Comment: The number of child exceptions is not a requirement and should not be tested this way. It's an implementation detail. You could check for 1+ exceptions of the correct type.

Comment: @HenkHolterman True but I do have to set up the mock appropriately. Are you suggesting I should set up for the maximum number of mock calls possible but not assert that all these were actually invoked at the end?

Comment: I'm not sure which part you want to mock but it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not test something like that - it's implementation detail.

Thing is - `Parallel.ForEach` will process elements until it gets exception. When exception occurs it will stop processnig any new elements (but will finish processing of the ones currently processed) and then throw `AgregateException`.

Now - your i7 CPU have 4 cores + Hyper Threading, which results in more threads spawned for processing, thus you can get more exceptions (because for example 4 things can be processed at the same time when exception occurs). But on Core2Duo with just 2 cores, only 2 items will be processed at the same time (it's because TPL is smart enough to create only enough threads for processing, not more than available cores).

Testing that actually 4 exception occured gives you no knowledge. It's machine dependent. You should instead test if at least one exception occured - since that's what you are expecting. If future user will run your code on old single core machine he will recieve just this one exception in `AggregateException`.

Number of thrown exception is machine specific, like for example calculation time - you would not assert on how long something was calculated, so you should not assert on number of exception in this case.

Comment: BTW, it's not just about the CPU. The specific behavior can also change depending on what else is running on the ThreadPool in the same process, what other processes are using the CPU, whether the operation in the loop is blocking and possibly other things.

Comment: Yes, that's completly true. CPU relationship is just the easiest one to spot, but all you mentioned is valid as well.

Comment: @Pako Thanks - your answer explains the problem very well. As I understand it, your solution is to set up the mock to allow the maximum number of exceptions (= threads) but then not actually assert that they all occurred. This seems slightly unusual in that normally when mocking I'm used to all the setups being verifiable.

Comment: When doing parallel processing you cannot easily assume that some thing will or will not happen, that's what makes it harder. Instead, you concentrate on signs that will tell you that something is working. The issue here is that `Parallel.ForEach` stops processing as soon as exception is spotted, while you were expecting it to process all items. If this does not satisfy you - you may fall back to setting max parallelism to 1 - but that's no good IMO. You caught exception - cool, that's what you expected, so you've proven your code working

Answer (score 1):

Unit test verifies that what you're expecting to happen and what actually happens are the same thing. That means you need to ask yourself what are you expecting to happen.

If you expect that all potential errors in processing will be reported, then your colleague's run actually found a bug in your code. This mean that plain `Parallel.ForEach()` won't work for you, but something like `Parallel.ForEach()` with a `try`-`catch` and custom exception processing would.

If what you expect is that each *thrown* exception will be caught, then that's what you need to test. This may complicate your test or it may not be possible to test, depending on how are you throwing the exceptions. A simple test for this would look like this:

```
[Test]
public void ParallelForEachExceptionsTest()
{
    var exceptions = new ConcurrentQueue<Exception>();
    var thrown = Assert.Throws<AggregateException>(
        () => Parallel.ForEach(
            Enumerable.Range(1, 4), i =>
            {
                var e = new Exception(i.ToString());
                exceptions.Enqueue(e);
                throw e;
            }));

    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(exceptions, thrown.InnerExceptions);
}
```

If what you expect is that when one or more exceptions are thrown, then at least some of them will be caught, then that's what you should test, and you shouldn't worry if all the exceptions were caught correctly.

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts here. It's the second case - each *thrown* exception must be caught. The thrown exceptions are actually coming from a method call on a mocked object. So as you say, I just need to verify that a subset of these are actually thrown.